# Can uniq be used to delete one duplicate line while retaining the other?

Tags: command-line, uniq

I have a file of numbers on different lines. There are many duplications. I would like to delete one line of the duplications while keeping the other line.

uniq -d deletes both lines. Is there a way to only delete one line while leaving the second identical line?

Comment: Shell commands use a different way of thinking: Input -> Process -> Output. Read File1, perform uniq, write the output as File2.

Answer (score 1):

- Sort the numbers with `sort`
- Remove the duplicates with `uniq`. You need no option.

Example with digits and two blank lines:

```
$ cat unsorted

1
2
3
1
2
3
4
3
2
1

$ sort unsorted


1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
$ sort unsorted | uniq

1
2
3
4
```

Comment: or with GNU, just `sort -u unsorted` to *"output only  the first of an equal run"*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output only the **first** occurrence of each line *without sorting*, use `awk` or `perl` to maintain a hash (associative array)

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print unless $h{$_}++' file
```

If you want to retain the **last** occurrence, then do the same thing but  read the file backwards and reverse it after:

```
tac file | awk '!a[$0]++' | tac
```

For more complicated deletions (such as deleting all but the second of *multiple* duplicates, while printing all non-duplicate lines) I think you will need to process the file twice.